# Network Interface Not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Every EC2 comes with a default network ETH0 and if we associate an elastic IP address to the default network interface, the IP is reachable.

Now, I disassociated the elastic IP to the default ETH0. Created a new network interface (ETH1) and associated the elastic ip. Attached the new network interface (ETH1) to the instance. But the elastic ip is not reachable or pingable.

Any idea why?

Comment: Are you running Windows or Linux? You'll need to configure the operating system to recognise the additional network interface.

Comment: Hi John, Its a ubuntu OS. Both the ETH network interfaces are detected in the OS while running ifconfig -a, but the ETH0 is seen with the private IP address, while the ETH1 does not seem to have any private IP address associated with the ifconfig output.

Answer (score 0):

While AWS does allocate a secondary IP address for your instance, I don't think DHCP can be used to automatically configure the IP address on your Ubuntu instance.

You will need to add the secondary IP address to your system configuration. I found a few resources that suggest ways to do this.

From [How to assign a second IP address on AWS Plesk for Ubuntu?](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001824353-How-to-assign-a-second-IP-address-on-AWS-Plesk-for-Ubuntu-):

> Connect to the instance via SSH and edit the /etc/network/interfaces.d/50-cloud-init.cfg file. Add the following lines at the bottom:

```
auto eth0:1 iface eth0:1 inet static address 172.31.16.199 << Your actual address
```

> Execute the following command to apply the changes:

```
systemctl restart networking
```

Other similar pages:

- [ubuntu - adding 2nd private IP on AWS EC2 instance - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/613040/adding-2nd-private-ip-on-aws-ec2-instance)
- [14.04 - add additional ipv4 addressess to the interface - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651308/add-additional-ipv4-addressess-to-the-interface)
- [networking - Add second IP-address to interface in 17.10 - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013021/add-second-ip-address-to-interface-in-17-10)

Comment: hi John,
Thanks for your reply. What I am trying to do here is, the public IP is associated with ETH0 which comes inbuilt while creating EC2 instance. But, when I disassociate public IP with ETH0 and associate the same address to ETH1, the IP does not seem to respond from internet or from outside.

Comment: Does the private IP communicate successfully within the VPC? You'll need to confirm that the private IP is working first, since the public IP simply maps to the private IP. The instance never actually knows its public IP.

Comment: I will check that and let you know shortly John.

Comment: Hi John, I have created a new EC2 instance with a default ETH0 with private IP (10.10.0.215) and dynamic default public ip (13.127.41.200). I have created a new interface ETH1 with ip 10.10.0.149 (private ip and same subnet as eth0). I have attached ETH1 to the EC2 instance.

I have logged in to the EC2 instance (UBUNTU) and tried to add the new static private ip for ETH1 in /etc/network/interfaces.d/50-cloud-init.cfg.
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static address 10.10.0.149
While restarting the services I got the below error (in next comment)

Comment: May 02 14:09:26 ip-10-10-0-215 sh[2257]: /etc/network/interfaces.d/50-cloud-init.cfg:13: extra parameter for
May 02 14:09:26 ip-10-10-0-215 ifup[2263]: /etc/network/interfaces.d/50-cloud-init.cfg:13: extra parameter fo
May 02 14:09:26 ip-10-10-0-215 ifup[2263]: Missing required variable: address
May 02 14:09:26 ip-10-10-0-215 ifup[2263]: Missing required configuration variables for interface eth1/inet.
May 02 14:09:26 ip-10-10-0-215 ifup[2263]: Failed to bring up eth1.
May 02 14:09:26 ip-10-10-0-215 systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited,